# Change timestamp date to today, but retain the hh:mm:ss part

Tags: mysql, sql, date, unix-timestamp

I have column declared
`time_stamp | timestamp| NO| PRI| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

I have some old data which I would like to use for testing posrpoises. Since my applciation defaults to displaying today's data, I would like an SQL command which changes the yyyy/nn//dd part to today, while retaining the hh:mm:ss part.

As the column is of type `timestamp`, I suspect I want something like

`UPDATE table SET time_stamp = time_stamp + (24*60*60* (now() - timestamp))` or similar, but I am unsure of the exact command.

I can haz halp?

---

```
 show create table positions;

| positions | CREATE TABLE `positions` (
  `vehicle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `distance_travelled` double NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `vehicle_id` (`vehicle_id`,`time_stamp`),
  CONSTRAINT `positions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicles` (`vehicle_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


select * from positions;

|          6 | 2013-10-22 17:24:57 | 1.33793333333333 | 103.755233333333 |               8483 | Pan Island Expressway, Singapore
                      |
|          6 | 2013-10-22 17:29:42 | 1.35208333333333 | 103.716433333333 |               7023 | 551 Jurong West Street 42, Singapore 640551
                      |
|          6 | 2013-10-22 17:34:42 | 1.35188333333333 | 103.715416666667 |                149 | 542 Jurong West Avenue 1, Singapore 640542
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
UPDATE table SET time_stamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp))))
```

[`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) will convert the unix timestamp into a datetime stamp which you can then easily extract the time portion by using [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time). Then you can concatenate the current date to it by using [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) with [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) which gets the current date and finally [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) which turns it back into a timestamp.

Comment: The answer really isn't much different.

Comment: I am getting errors (I added a WHERE vehcile_id=3, just to test without possibly destroying all data).  I get "ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3-2014-02-20 HH:MM:SS' for key 'vehicle_id'" where HH:MM:SS is the time that I run your command. There are no such "HH:MM:SS" in the exisiting data.

Comment: Hmm, if I "select TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_Stamp))  from positions" it retunrs NULL for every row,

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME()` converts the unix timestamp into a datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) so it is there. That error means you have a unique index or primary key on that column and you have a duplicate entry for that value. Although I don;t think this will affect things, I did realize that I did not turn the final result back into a unix timestamp. Try it out and see if it helps. If it doesn't, check your  indices and primary keys.

Comment: Can you show a value from the time_Stamp column? Also, can you post the datatype it is as defined in your create statement?

Comment: Either get rid of ` ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or don't manually update the column yourself as this code already does it for you.

Comment: You probably should also remove the time_stamp column from your unique key as it don't think it is necessary and clearly problematic

Comment: Thanks, those are both good points. But, how do I change the date, not time, in an existing database, for testing porpoises?